# What is the Description in WMAppMaifest.xml used for?

Tags: windows-phone-7, publishing, marketplace

I'm trying to correctly fill in WMAppManifest.xml before I submit my app to the marketplace, but I'm not sure what to put in the Description field.  It seems like all of that sort of info is taken from what you enter in the website when you submit your app, not the manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the description attribute is ignored when you submit to the marketplace. So you can just leave it blank.

Only the title attribute is used for regular apps. Mind you the publisher field is , if I recall correctly, used for XNA apps and music/picture hub integration.

Comment: Yes, the contents of the file that gets deployed in your XAP is generated at submission time based on the details you supply during submission.